# Google cloud speech api javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am working on an angular project where Google cloud speech api has to be used for speech input . I went through the official docs : https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries .

There are example codes available for Node.js, PHP and other server side languages.
But, I couldn't find any examples using JavaScript.

Is there any way to use the cloud speech api using JavaScript or angular 5?
If yes, could somebody provide pointers for the sample code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can you use the npm packages for your angular 5 project.
https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages
Therefore, you can just use the node.js code examples in the link that you put. 
So you need to install the package

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/speech
```

and use the example code as in node.js section.

Comment: Thanks. But, is there any way to code the logic in the client side(angular) , instead of the node.js section?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe you can find some github projects, but as I said before, you can use, node.js examples for angular with slight changes. I was in your situation couple month before, needed to use cloud vision api, and I used node.js examples cause they both are typescript which worked fine.